# Creating a large virtual table in FROM clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Background**

I have a Java application which periodically takes a resultset from one database (MySQL), and attempts to find matches in another database (Postgres / PostGIS to be specific).

**Problem**

Presently, the application queries the Postgres database once for ever MySQL record in the result set (could be upwards of tens of thousands). I'm attempting to alter the algorithm so that the application generates one single query that yields multiple results if any matches are found. Another way to describe my goal is that the query should behave similar to a typical JOIN, if these two tables existed within the same database system.

**Current Solution**

In order to solve this, I'm creating a virtual table in the `FROM` clause. However, the only way I know how to do this from a list of values is by writing individual `SELECT` statements joined with a `UNION`. The result appears to work, and while I haven't tested for performance with thousands of records, it doesn't appear to have any massive impact using hundreds of such `SELECT`-`UNION` statements. This is the relevant portion of the overall query to illustrate what I have done so far:

```
SELECT *, ST_Distance_Sphere(latlng, geom) as distance 
FROM rwis_sites 
    INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 1100 as unit_id, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-81.19701 32.09279)', 4326) as geom UNION
 SELECT 1100 as unit_id, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-81.19682 32.09224)', 4326) as geom 
  UNION
 SELECT 1100 as unit_id, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-81.1968 32.09213)', 4326) as geom 
  UNION
... just a few more...hundred...thousand...
 SELECT 2266 as unit_id, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-97.98719 29.57656)', 4326) as geom 
  UNION
 SELECT 2266 as unit_id, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-97.98815 29.57602)', 4326) as geom
) virtualTable 
ON ST_Distance_Sphere(latlng, geom) < 10000 
ORDER BY ST_Distance_Sphere(latlng, geom) ASC limit 1
```

Since the "virtual table" is generated programmatically, there is little effort on my part.

**Question**

However, I am concerned whether this is a "goofy" approach (not to mention any performance issues I've yet to detect), and ultimately I am wondering: is there is a better way of creating something similar without thousands of `SELECT`-`UNION` statements?

Comment: Can you export out of MySQL the required data to a delineated file and then use the PostgreSQL COPY command to import into a PostgreSQL staging table. From there query your main table with the import table you created.

Comment: @Bob Oh ok, that's an interesting idea. I'll look in to that; as long as it can be done programmatically from the Java application, and doesn't negatively affect performance. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a better way to create a table of [values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-values.html) on the fly

```
select *
from (
  values
    (1100::int, 'POINT(-81.19701 32.09279)'::geography(Point)),
    (1100::int, 'POINT(-81.19682 32.09224)'::geography(Point))
) as t(unit_id, geom)
```

Yet even better idea is perhaps to use [foreign data wrapper](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#mysql_fdw) to bring your mysql table in PG.

**EDIT**

You might want to try to pre-screen records from your main table provided it is indexed with `ST_Dwithin(latlng, geom, 0.1)` provided that 0.1° is just [slightly more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) (mind cos(32.09)) than 10000 m.

Comment: Ah ok, very nice. Thus far, I don't detect any noticeable performance difference with this method, but it looks a lot cleaner, and I likely avoid the performance issue of `UNION` that Marlin mentioned. I will look further into the data wrapper, I didn't realize this existed. Thanks for that!

Comment: You can't benefit from spatial index with "on the fly table", so it might be slow if both tables have many records. You do you have a spatial index on `rwis_sites(latlng)` as Marlin Pierce mentioned, right? Though it is usually used with ST_DWithin. Also it might be better if you pass [Well Known Binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) instead of a text to be converted to geography if your client library supports it. [Prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) might help if you call it often.

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend using "UNION ALL" instead of "UNION".  When you use UNION, it tries to remove duplicates, which is work you don't need it to do.  As you have thousands of values, checking for duplicates will become slow.

I cannot think of another way than the SELECT to populate the virtual table in one SQL statement.  You might try to populate a temporary table in one SQL statement, and then do the join in a second.  However, that brings up transaction issues, so you might want to stick with the way you have it.

As another performance helpful hint, your inner join is evaluating

```
ST_Distance_Sphere(latlng, geom) < 10000
```

for every combination of each of the records in rwis_sites and the (possibly thousands) records in your virtual table, and it has no way to use an index to optimize it.  If you index on one axis of the points, use a range of 10000 in your join, and move the ST_Distance_Sphere to the where clause it will likely run faster.  Paradoxically, you are adding more work, but if it checked the range first, it can use the index to disqualify many of the combinations, and only check the actual distance when the points are close along one axis.

Comment: Thanks for the `UNION ALL` tip. Re: temporary table, I thought of that too; haven't tried it yet, but it could potentially work, and transaction issues might not be a problem right now until I need to scale the number of processes. Re: The distance join performance, I'm confused about one thing: you said *"use a range of 10000 in your join, and move the ST_Distance_Sphere"* to the where clause..., I'm not quite clear on what you're advising should go in the join. The *"use a range of 10000"* part is throwing me off, do you mean perform the same `ST_Distance...` in both clauses?

Comment: The transaction issues arise from using a temporary table because your web server will create multiple threads.  If you delete all the rows in a temporary table and insert new rows, it could get messy if multiple threads are interleaving calls to delete insert and select.

Comment: For the range comment, I certainly do not mean repeating the same condition. 
 
Index one axis, such as the longitude.  In the join, instead of "ST_Distance_Sphere(latlng, geom) < 10000" use "long between -97.98815 - R and -97.98815 + R".  The value of R will be a constant representing 10000 but converted to longitude difference along the prime meridian.
 
The join clause will use an index which is fast to pre-qualify points that are close enough north to south that are possibly within 10000 of the given point.  You will save time be quickly disqualifying points which cannot be within 10000.